# Ajax / jQuery ? Need help to add parameter to pass

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm learning ajax/jQuery and have some problem. Code :

```
    .click(function() {
        var periode = 'ALL';
        if ($('#registerat input:checked').val() != 'ALL')
          periode = $('#sdate').val() + '-' + $('#edate').val();
          name = $('#merchant');
        oTable.fnReloadAjax('reportuserdata.php?ala=' + alaid + '&periode=' + encodeURI(periode));
        return false;
    });
```

I want to add this **name** (selected from selectbox, Is this the right syntax?) parameter to the reportuserdata.php, maybe like this?

```
oTable.fnReloadAjax('reportuserdata.php?ala=' + alaid + '&periode=' + encodeURI(periode) + '&merchant' + encodeURI(nama));
```

selectbox :

```
<select name="merchant" id="merchant"> </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 name = $('#merchant').val();

 ...'&merchant' + encodeURI(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get the value of the element using `.val()` then just append it to the url

```
var name = $('#merchant').val();
oTable.fnReloadAjax('reportuserdata.php?ala=' + alaid + '&periode=' + encodeURI(periode) + '&name=' + encodeURI(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to call .val() on merchant so you get the value and not just the dom reference.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value in dropdown

```
$('#merchant').val();
```

To get the selected text in dropdown

```
$('#merchant :selected').text();
```